# Prevent buffer loads within NERDTree

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-nerdtree

If I have many buffers opened and, if the cursor (focus) is within NERDTree, when I change the buffer with `:bn` or `:bp`, the content of buffer loads within NERDTree.

There's a way to, before buffer enter, check if cursor is focus on NERDTree and type `<c-w><c-w>` to prevent buffer loads within NERDTree?

Comment: Something along the lines of `autocmd BufUnload nerdtree <your commands here>`, maybe. There are a lot of posts that deal with nerdtree specific buffers...maybe not this question exactly but similar enough to reveal some useful information.

Comment: Tks @BLayer! I will try solutions and post here if I found something.

Comment: Sounds good. There will probably be some degree of scripting required, even if it's just the rest of an autocmd line like I mentioned so if you're not experienced with that just try to get a rough idea, come back and update your question with any relevant new details and we'll go from there. (If you are experienced you might figure it all out for yourself.)

Comment: If you want an easy workaround start using Normal mode mappings to cycle through buffers and use a mapping like this for `:bnext` ... `:nnoremap <silent> <leader>n :if &filetype != 'nerdtree' <bar> :bnext <bar> endif<cr>` and similar for `:bprev`. (I use such mappings for `bnext`/`bprev`  even without having a requirement like yours...it's quicker!)

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

One can use `interrupt()` to abort event in progress. So for NERDtree one could do something like:

```vim
autocmd BufWinLeave * if &filetype == 'nerdtree' | call interrupt() | endif
```

> BufWinLeave
>
> Before a buffer is removed from a window. Not when it's still visible in another window. Also triggered when exiting.  It's triggered before BufUnload or BufHidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I chose:

```
function! IsSideBar(buf_nr)
" Return 1 if the buffer correspond to a side bar:
" - A terminal window
" - The quickfix window
" - The help
" - The NERDTree side bar
" - ...
  let buf_name = bufname(a:buf_nr)
  let buf_type = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&filetype')
  let readonly = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&readonly')

  let term_buffers = term_list()

  if buf_type ==# 'qf'
    " QuickFix, LocationList:
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'help'
    " Help Window:
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'undotree'
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'tagbar'
    return 1

  elseif buf_type ==# 'nerdtree'
    return 1

  elseif index(term_buffers, a:buf_nr) >= 0
    " echom 'Console'
    return 1

  else
    return 0

  endif
endfunction

function! LeaveSideBar()
  " Go to a non side bar window
  let loop = 0
  while 1
    let loop = loop + 1
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')

    if loop > 10
      " Don't search for more than 10 windows
      " To handle the case all the windows are 'side bars'
      break
    endif

    if IsSideBar(bufnr)
      wincmd w
    else
      break
    endif

  endwhile
endfunction

command! LeaveSideBar call LeaveSideBar()

function! NERDTreeExplore(...)
  if a:0 == 0
    NERDTree %:p:h
  else
    if isdirectory(a:1)
      execute printf("NERDTree %s", a:1)
    else
      call LeaveSideBar()
      execute printf("e %s", a:1)
    endif
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=* -complete=file E call NERDTreeExplore(<f-args>)
```

I have created a `LeaveSideBar` command that moves the cursor outside of the side bars (NERDTree but also UndoTree, TagBar, QuickFix, Terminal, ...) and I have replaced the method that open buffer (`:e`, `:bn`) by custom variant (`:E`, `:Bn`) that call `LeaveSideBar` first.